# Unhandled exception while calling setFixedSize() from Qt5Widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I'm developing a code using Qt library in visual studio.
I have a class A as Child of Qt classes.

`class A::A(QWidget *parent, QGLWidget *shareWidget)
     : QGLWidget(parent, shareWidget)`

one of the member function of this class is:

```
void A::setImage(Image *image)
{
    m_image = image;
    setFixedSize(image->width(), image->height());
}
```

(in which setFixedSize is a method of the parent class QWidget)

this method is called in the following event from another class:

```
bool B::event(QEvent* e)
{
    QWidget::event(e);
    ...

    A instA = new A();
    instA.setImage(*image)
    ...

}
```

the following exception is thrown at setFixedSize, although the passed values are really normal int like width = height = 500.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x54A6B056 (Qt5Widgetsd.dll):
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x939394BC.
```

this method setImage ist called several time while runing the code, and it works just great. The problem apears only in B::event(QEvent* e).

PS: The method is not working at this point, even if I pass directly the constant values like setFixedSize(500, 500).

Looking forward to any suggestion.

Comment: Please improve your question ( see also [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ), especially: Complete the `setImage` function signature, show the full implementation of `B::event` and provide a full stack-trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
A instA = new A();
instA.setImage(*image)
```

This looks absurd to me. Can you please give exact compiled code.

Second, while using `pointers` pls make sure they are not `null`

So your function should be like this-

```
void A::setImage(Image *image)
{
   if(image)  //Null check, it will enter to block only if image is not null
   {
    m_image = image;
    setFixedSize(image->width(), image->height());
   }
}
```

Comment: The pointer is not null at this moment. I can read that at that moment. I do even see the values which are passed to setFixedSize(). But I should confess that I haven't summerized my code so well. I should edit that.